# Understanding how to use conditional statements with python

Tags: python

```
def greater_less_equal_5(answer):
    if ___ :
        return 1
    elif ___:          
        return -1
    else:
        return 0

print greater_less_equal_5(4)
print greater_less_equal_5(5)
print greater_less_equal_5(6)
```

(On line 2, fill in the if statement to check if answer is greater than 5.
On line 4, fill in the elif so that the function outputs -1 if answer is less than 5.)

Comment: Don't be "that guy".  Read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: What about it are you stuck on? What are you trying to get it to print?

Comment: To find the right answer, ask the right question. What is the question you need an answer to?

Comment: `answer < 5` returns `True` if `answer` is less than `5`. Hopefully you can figure out the reverse one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def greater_less_equal_5(answer):
    if answer>5 :
        return 1
    elif answer<5:          
        return -1
    else:
        return 0

print greater_less_equal_5(4)
print greater_less_equal_5(5)
print greater_less_equal_5(6)
```

Try this